# Send a percentage or count of emails to another server with Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

We are moving our Postfix outbound mail servers into an AWS region. We have the new external IP addresses with neutral reputation and can't move the old ones. We'd like to warm up the new IPs before moving the entire load by sending a percentage or total count of our legitimate email to the new servers with the new IPs.

Is it possible to configure Postfix on the old servers to relay a measurable portion of mail through these new servers so that they can begin to build reputation before we assign them full responsibility?

Comment: You can use transport table feature of postfix to transfer some (preferably not very important) destinations over the new server. It is possible to include a custom script in master.cf but that is not needed in your case imho.

Comment: Unimportant destinations would not warm up the IP with the big names that I need to start expecting high volumes of mail from those IPs. I'm assuming that would also mean less impact on improving our reputation from Neutral to Good.

Comment: I don't have enough details to make this an answer, but what about using an SMTP capable software load balancer?

Comment: Ed Grimm, I've looked at using haproxy in between for this. For the temporary setup to warm up the IPs, it starts to have a bad ROI. If I already had an haproxy infrastructure (or some other SMTP capable LB) it would totally make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a "simple" TCP server that would return the relay server to use. This would follow the `tcp_table` format:

http://www.postfix.org/tcp_table.5.html

Another option, depending what these emails are, you could use header based routing and you could add a `X-NextRelay` header and determine the next hop from that. That would place the decision of which relay to use to the system generating the email. This is done with http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html - you can then have a regex file like

```
/^X-NextRelay: (.*)$/ FILTER smtp:$1
```

These are two ideas that come to mind.

Comment: Header based routing wouldn't work, but I'm mulling on the tcp_table. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, found I can write a simple script that just counts to a number and then sends a response "200 smtp:[my-endpoint.com]" once and a "200 smtp:" every other time. I think that'll work well. Sure appreciate you sending me down this path.

Comment: Argh, tcp_table isn't compiled into the version of postfix I'm using on the servers and an update isn't available. So close!

Comment: `tcp` lookups are overkill for the goal, `pcre` is *good enough*. Match on a subset of characters (`/^...[a-f]/`) in `transport` for stable selections per-recipient - or fully random in `header_checks` for unique `Message-Id`.